# ¿Cómo puedo desencriptar un dato encripado con bcrypt en laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5

He buscado en todos lados pero solo consigo como encriptar y desencriptar con `encrypt` y `decrypt`, pero yo necesito desencriptar un dato `bcrypt`.

Intente con `decrypt` pero es diferente a `bcrypt`. Creí inocentemente que se podía.

Encripto de la siguiente manera:

```
bcrypt($req->password)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La función bcrypt es una función de Hash, esta especialmente diseñada para que no se pueda descifrar de ninguna forma.

Normalmente se usa solo con contraseñas usando el metodo:

`Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)`

Para comprobar si la contraseña es correcta o no.

En el caso de que quieras un cifrado reversible tienes que usar `encrypt` en vez de `bcrypt`

Comment: El problema q tengo con encrypt es que no me deja loguear con el usuario ya que desencripta con bcrypt para comparar con el usuario

Comment: Si lo que quieres es cifrado de contraseñas, tienes que usar bcrypt('my-secret-password'); durante el registro del usuario y cuando cambies la contraseña del usuario y Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword) cuando el usuario inicia sesión. No es necesario descifrar la contraseña para comprobar si la que ha introducido el usuario es correcta o no. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/hashing

Comment: Como dato complementario al que te da Fernando, por ahi no lo entendes, Hash::check() te retorna true o false, asique si lo colocas dentro de un if, estaría la solución, es muy común cuando queres cambiar una contraseña y pedís la confirmacion. Otra solucion que provee laravel es la de make: auth. que te genera un login entre otras cosas, utiles para no tener que manejar estas cosas